# Is Shemittah a mitzvah bein odom laMokom or bein odom lechaveiro?

Tags: shmita, bein-adam-lachavero, bein-adam-lamakom

The [Ksav Sofer](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14083&hilite=38487a73-80d6-42a7-8574-212a1aeee9bf&st=%d7%a1%d7%99%d7%a0%d7%99&pgnum=417) says about the owner making his produce ownerless in the 7th year,

> ואם אז יפקיר הכל שיהי׳ העני שוה לו ליטול כל מה שירצה אין לו ואהבה לרעך
>   יותר מזה
>
> If a person makes his produce ownerless so that the poor person can
>   take whatever he wants, there is no greater “love your neighbour as
>   yourself” than this.

Rabbi Immanuel Bernstein [Dimensions in Chumash, Parshas Behar](https://journeysintorah.com/wp-content/uploads/dimensions_behar_2020.pdf) points out that Shemittah takes the concept of giver and receiver out of the act of kindness between people. (The land becomes hefker).

If there is no giver,  it seems to me that Shemittah must be a mitzvah bein odom laMokom.

What is the right way to think about Shemittah? Is it essentially a mitzvah bein odom laMokom or bein odom lechaveiro?

Comment: Does it have to be only exactly one of those?

Comment: Can't this be asked about any mitzvah of chessed and tzedaka? Are we doing and giving because we feel for the individual, or because Hashem said to. (Reb Moshe said it's a combination of both)

Comment: @DoubleAA עבירות שבין אדם למקום, יום הכיפורים מכפר.

עבירות שבין אדם לחבירו, אין יום הכיפורים מכפר, עד שירצה את חבירו (Yoma 8:9). It seems that there are exactly two options, with a practical distinction depending on which one it is

Comment: @ba why can't something be both with eachs chumra

Comment: A related question would ask whether the land becomes hefker independent of the actions of the owner or whether the owner has to declare it hefker.

Comment: Rabbi Shlomo Yosef Zevin http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/sinay/shmita-4.htm

Comment: @DoubleAA There is only one chumra I see here. Either you have to ask for forgiveness or you don't

Comment: @ba could be but that doesn't seem to matter here

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% excluding the possibility that *shemittas karka*, letting one's land be ownerless,  is considered an interpersonal *mitzvah* (you show the **Kesav Sofer** seems to think so), I'd like to share that it would seem to be **Rav Saadiah Gaon**'s opinion that this *mitzvah* is between Man and G-d.

In his *Azharos* based on the Ten Commandments, he classifies the 613 *mitzvos* into each of the Ten Commandments. In the *mitzvah* of זכור (Shabbos), [he writes](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=20685#p=261&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=):

> שפתים והפרורים תשמט בשביעית ספיחיה ונזיריה **לא תגדור**

**Rav Yerucham Fishel Perla** [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Positive_Commandments.61.27?vhe=Sefer_Hamitzvot_L%27Rasag,_Warsaw,_1914_--_vol._1&lang=he) this to be referring to the *mitzvah* of *shemittas karka*. I believe the consensus is that Shabbos is between Man and G-d. It would seem then that **Rav Saadiah Gaon** understands this *mitzvah* to be as well.

<sub>Although perhaps you could argue the other *mitzvos* of *shemittah* clearly have a connection to Shabbos, and he grouped this one together with them.</sub>